# Compute FFT in PHP language

Tags: php, arrays, fft

I'm working on a project to compute Fast Fourier Transform(FFT) on every 5 numbers in an array of numbers. For instance, i've group the numbers into groups of 5 as shown below:

**CODE:**

```
    $arrayCount = count($output);

    for ($x = 0; $x < $arrayCount; $x++)

    {

        if($x%5==0)

        {

              echo ("\n");


        }

        echo json_encode($output[$x]);  

    }
```

**RESULT:**

```
"671""1265""527""854""646"

"1255""601""603""1089""543"
```

How do I compute FFT in php for each row (5 numbers)? Is there any fft library for PHP that I can use to compute them or is there any formulas that I can use?

Comment: Is something like this what you're looking for? https://gist.github.com/mbijon/1332348

Comment: Are you sure you know what you want to do? The FFT expects that the length of the input is a power of two. Also, please at least read the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fft). You'll find that the usual FFT algorithm is [Cooley-Tukey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooley%E2%80%93Tukey_FFT_algorithm), which is explained with formulae and everything. :)